# Why the result onkeyup is different? (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, onkeyup

I have these codes below to calculate the final score. But when i checked in calculator the result is different. May i know why?

**The Code** :

```js
function calculate() {
    var a = $("#sc1").val();
    var b = $("#sc2").val();
    var c = $("#sc3").val();
    scavg = (parseInt(a) + parseInt(b) + parseInt(c)) /3;
    scavg = scavg.toFixed(2);
    $("#scavg").val(scavg);
    var d = $("#scavg").val();
    var e = $("#np").val();
    f =  (parseInt(e)*3 + parseInt(d)*7) /10 
    $("input[name=na]").val(f);           
}
```

Comment: "Different" from what?

Comment: @Teemu the results from function calculte is different in web and  calculator. For example, in web the final score is 75.4 and in calculator 75.7. The difference is 0.3

Comment: Maybe you should add the used parameters and the wanted result, and the unexpeted results you'll get, to the post itself.

Comment: @uchuneno Use `parseFloat()` instead of `parseInt()` see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`parseInt()` return integers which are whole numbers. The format of `scavg` is a float if you want to show decimal numbers to the hundreth (`.toFixed(2)`), `parseFloat()` is what you need to use.

#### Demo

```js
function calculate() {
  var a = $("#sc1").val();
  var b = $("#sc2").val();
  var c = $("#sc3").val();
  scavg = (parseFloat(a) + parseFloat(b) + parseFloat(c)) / 3;
  scavg = scavg.toFixed(2);
  $("#scavg").val(scavg);
  var d = $("#scavg").val();
  var e = $("#np").val();
  var f = (parseFloat(e) * 3 + parseFloat(d) * 7) / 10
  $("input[name=na]").val(f);
}

$('input').on('input', calculate);
```

```css
input {
  font: inherit;
  display: block
}
```

```html
<input id='sc1' type='number' step="0.01" placeholder='SC1'>
<input id='sc2' type='number' step="0.01" placeholder='SC2'>
<input id='sc3' type='number' step="0.01" placeholder='SC3'>
<input id='scavg' type='number' step="0.01" placeholder='scAvg'>
<input id='np' type='number' step="0.01" placeholder='NP'>
<input name='na' type='number' step="0.01" placeholder='NA'>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi @zer00ne it's works like a charm..
thank's a lot :)

Comment: No problem, happy coding @uchuneno